# Out of Memory Issue(java.lang.outofmemory) in J2ME LWUIT

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia, nokia-s40, lwuit-resource-editor

I am developing J2ME (LWUIT) Application without any theme.
In Nokia 206 device am facing Out of Memory issue (java.lang.outofMemory)
My JAR size is 404 KB 
This issue is not coming consistent it is coming sometimes
I have done R and D on this issue but did not get any Proper Solution. 
If any one have any idea please help me on solving this issue.

**More Specifications :-----**

I am working on Questionnaire app, which has screens with dynamic fields data handling, means UI LWUIT components are created by parsing and reading from JSON object received from server, same way send the data dynamically to server using JSON, meanwhile when i try to make transaction app shows outOfMemory issue, sometimes it doesn't show for 10 transactions and sometime it shows in 1-2 transactions after login.

I tried with making transaction exit app, again login and make transaction then after some attemt just after login i get outOfMemory issue.

I am using LWUIT library, i checked removing the theme from app but still the problem exist.

What could be the issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please explain more where and on which functionality you are getting this issue???

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of app are you developing? What are the conditions when the out of memory error occurs? If you can't include this basic information then your guess is as good as ours!

Comment: I have edited question please refer to it

Comment: We'll have to guess. And I'm guessing it might be caused by JSON objects that becomes too big. When JSON data is parsed, you could get an OOM Exception if the amount of data is too big.

Answer (score 0):

> reading from JSON object received from server, same way send the data
>   dynamically to server using JSON

This is likely your problem. You are most likely spawning network threads but not cleaning them up. Do you have the same issue if you don't make any network transactions?

Try using your emulators memory diagnostic if its available and see when the RAM spikes up.

EDIT: We still need more details if you want help, post what you've tried already or some sample code and help us narrow it down

Fenix